# Parse Math Expression as "3 + 2 * temp + humidity", where replace alpha values from payload

Tags: python, pyparsing

Math Expression can be anything. The variable or alpha character here in expression are also not fixed "3 + 2 * temp + humidity". The variable must look for json and get replaced by it's value from json.

```
environment = {"temp": 23, "humidity": 12, "airpressure":21.12}
expression = '3 + 2 * temp + humidity'
```

the response I am looking is as `'3 + 2 * 23 + 12'.`

as I just started exploring  `pyparsing` I  couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I won't upvote nor downvote, but members of the community will certainly ask you to show what have you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you just want to replace the strings `'temp'` and `'humidity'` by the numbers `23` and `12`, or do you also want to evaluate the resulting string `'3 + 2 * 23 + 12'` as an arithmetic expression to get the number 61?

Comment: BTW, you may want to take a look at this similar (but more complex) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744290/parse-a-list-of-expressions-using-pyparsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the keys of your `environment` dictionary to a regular expression, and then replace them with the corresponding value:

```
def resolve_vars(expression, environment):
    regex = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join([re.escape(k) for k in environment]))
    repl = lambda s: str(environment.get(s.group(), s.group()))
    return re.sub(regex, repl, expression)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a regex to look for the variables, and use `re.sub` to replace each matched variable by its value:

```
import re

environment = {"temp": 23, "humidity": 12, "airpressure":21.12}
expression = '3 + 2 * temp + humidity'

def replace_var(m):
    return str(environment[m.group(0)])

def replace_vars(expression):
    return re.sub(r'[a-z]+', replace_var, expression)  # assuming your variables are all lowercase

print(replace_vars(expression))
# 3 + 2 * 23 + 12
```

This will raise a `KeyError` in case a variable doesn't exist in `environment`.